# D3 Heatmap Syntax

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, matrix

So, my task is to help implement a few visuals in a web environment. Specifically, I am trying to build a heat map from a simple dummy matrix representing a small dataset from a JSON file using d3 in JS.  The input data is this:

```
{"data":[[8,2],[5,4],[9,6]]}
```

So, again, how would you visualize the above data in a heat map matrix using d3?

Comment: You need to give more detail explanation what you want exactly. what heatmap you want and based on what parameters color will be defined in heat map.. What is the meaning of that json data as well

Comment: the heatmap colors could range like this: ['white', "#69b3a2"]

Comment: Also, for this data I intend to name the three rows as [a, b, c] and the two columns as [x,y]. This is just a test as I am trying to build a simple heat map to later make a bigger one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

Hope below code helps..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const data = {"data":[[8,2],[5,4],[9,6]]};
// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Labels of row and columns
var rows = [];
var cols = [];
var chartData = [];
data.data.forEach((item, i) => {
  if( i === 0) {
    item.forEach((itm , j) => {
      cols.push("col" + j);
      chartData.push({ row: "row" + i, col: "col" + j,value: itm});
    });
  } else {
     item.forEach((itm , j) => {
      chartData.push({ row: "row" + i, col: "col" + j, value: itm});
    });
  }
  rows.unshift("row" + i);
})


// Build X scales and axis:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(cols)
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

// Build X scales and axis:
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ height, 0 ])
  .domain(rows)
  .padding(0.01);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Build color scale
var myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["white", "#69b3a2"])
  .domain([1,100])
console.log(chartData);
//Read the data
  svg.selectAll()
      .data(chartData, function(d) {return d.row+':'+d.col;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.col) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.row) })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )


</script>
```

Running example.. [working example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mum88z)

Comment: Wow, looks great. Thanks